# Using TFS 2013 code reviews with alternative source control

Tags: tfs

We're using TFS for our day-to-day work management, but are currently unable to use it for source control - we're using SVN instead.

I would like to nonetheless ensure that all our work items have been code reviewed before being closed, and that any code review actions have been followed up on. Any recommendations on how we can keep track of this using TFS with minimal manual steps?

I am also concerned with ensuring that the code review step has not been skipped, and auditability of whether it has happened and whether all resulting actions were closed off. If I look at a closed task, how can I easily tell that a code review occurred on it?

Comment: Can you explain more specifically challenges you are dealing with? For example, why not simply use a Task for every code review request?

Comment: This would be a back-up option but it relies on people remembering to create the task and it becomes hard to track whether someone has just closed off a dev task without creating a review task.

Comment: My point is that you should add those concerns to your question so we know exactly what constraints you are trying to apply.

Comment: OK thanks, does the edit to the question cover it?

Comment: Does this go anyway towards solving the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8740444/how-to-do-code-reviewing-with-tfs/8740715#8740715

Comment: @DaveShaw, that would be a perfect solution if our source control was integrated with TFS but unfortunately it isn't - however I will bear it in mind in case we migrate in the future.

Answer (score 0):

1. (Optional) Require that every SVN change refer to a work item number in TFS with the check-in comments.
2. The work item in TFS has a "LINKS" tab on it. As soon as the code is checked in, another work item of type "Task" (or whatever you want to use for code reviews) should be created and linked to the primary work item on this LINKS tab to request the code review for that work item. It should refer to the SVN revision number(s) that need(s) review.
3. I'm not very familiar with SVN, but I assume there is a way to have branches that could be used as follows. Maintain a separate branch for reviewed code. Only code reviewers can merge into that branch. The only way code can get in there is if the proper work item in TFS exists, and a code reviewer approves and merges the code for it. I'm used to Mercurial and TFS where merging code is really easy. If merging is not easy in SVN, a different solution may be required.
4. If the linked task exists on a work item, then you know that the code has been checked in and code review is in process. If the link exists, and the linked work item is resolved, then you know the code review is complete. If the link does not exist, then you know that code has not been checked in for this work item (or at least it's not in the reviewed code branch, and has no intent to be there).

Comment: Thank you for the above suggestions. Having spoken to Microsoft, it seems that without customising TFS (which we aren't able to do in my organisation), it will not be possible to meet my requirements. As a workaround, we will be using the "resolved" column to mean "ready for code review" and the "closed" column to mean that the code review passed. Adding a duplicate linked item for every task will add too many overheads I feel.

Answer (score -1):

We have decided to edit the TFS workflow to include an extra 'In Review' state after 'Resolved'. This allows us to use the existing task board without any overhead of creating separate review tasks, or having to edit the task title to be 'in review: ....

Comment: Your question from over a year ago wasn't clear and this isn't an answer to it. Consider deleting the original question for the sake of future google searches looking for help with TFS

Comment: @Jonathon If I try to delete it, it says I can't since it has answers.